# Gerenciar atividade de iframe

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Boa noite pessoal!!! vim pedir um help a vocês. Estou montando uma página .php com estrutura html que contem um IFrame em seu corpo. Logo quando esta página .php é aberta o iframe carrega dentro de si uma página da web que não é gerenciada por mim, mas tenho como obter os id´s de seus botões, inputs, div´s etc. Bom, lá vai a pergunta, há como gerenciar a atividade nesta página web que está sendo carregada dentro de um iframe na minha página .php? Há como capturar os clicks de botões e entradas de input que forem realizados nesta página web? Por favor se alguém souber fico muitíssimo agradecida!!! Ainda não entendo muito de javascript, mas buscando nos sites da vida achei este código abaixo, tentei implementar os id´s de elementos da página web, mas não deu certo. Obs.: o id `IFrame` é do `IFrame` da minha página em que está sendo carregada a página da web e o `ember516` é o id de um input da página da web.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendDataToIFrame(){
        var EUREKA = document.getElementById('IFrame').contentDocument.getElementById('ember516');
        EUREKA.innerHTML = "EUREKA!!!";
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<center><h3>VIDEOCENTER</h3></center>
<br>
<center><iframe id="IFrame" style="border:0; width:90%; height:900px; " src="linkdapáginaweb.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), você consegue pegar através do seguinte código.

```
$("#IFrame").contents()
```

Assim você pode ter acesso ao conteúdo. Mas isso só vai dar certo se ambos os sites (o seu e o do iframe) tiverem a mesma URL da Origem. Se tentar fazer com um site de terceiros, você vai receber um erro de *cross-origin*:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "outro site" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Os browsers privam este tipo de acesso por questão de segurança.

Comment: vlw @DouglasFernandes q pena que não dá :(